# C# Methods - which arguments go where?

Tags: c#, methods

Disclaimer: I am a very new programmer, so you may have to break this down like I am five years old.

I have a very basic overview of methods in C# and have an assignment to convert alphanumeric inputs into a seven-digit phone number.  At the moment, I have enough code to get the input (entered all at once: 1234567) and have it displayed in telephone number format.  However, I need to run checks on my input so the values are correct -- no symbols, first character != 0, and first three characters != 555.

Here is the code I have thus far:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char c1 = ' '; 
            char c2 = ' '; 
            char c3 = ' ';
            char c4 = ' ';
            char c5 = ' ';
            char c6 = ' ';
            char c7 = ' ';

            int returnVal = 0;

            GetInput(ref c1, ref c2, ref c3, ref c4, ref c5, ref c6, ref c7);

            returnVal = ProcessInput(ref c1, ref c2, ref c3, ref c4, ref c5, ref c6, ref c7);
            if (returnVal == -1) {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, please try again. "); }
            else {
                ShowResults(ref c1, ref c2, ref c3, ref c4, ref c5, ref c6, ref c7); }
        }


        static void GetInput(ref char x1, ref char x2, ref char x3, ref char x4, ref char x5, ref char x6, ref char x7)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a 7 character phone number: ");
            x1 = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
            x2 = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
            x3 = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
            x4 = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
            x5 = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
            x6 = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
            x7 = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        static int ProcessInput(ref char y1, ref char y2, ref char y3, ref char y4, ref char y5, ref char y6, ref char y7)
        {
            return 0;
        }


        static void ShowResults(ref char z1, ref char z2, ref char z3, ref char z4, ref char z5, ref char z6, ref char z7)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The converted phone number is: {0}{1}{2}-{3}{4}{5}{6} ", z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6, z7);
        }

    }
```

What I'm lost on is how to run these arguments and where they actually go (into which  method?).  Any help is appreciated and I will clarify where I can.  Thank you.

Comment: Yikes! Don't do that :) Use a *string* (or at least an *sequence* of characters) - do *not* use variables for each single digit! It is just *too hard* to deal with. Also, don't use `ref` unless it is *really* required. It isn't in this case, once making the suggested change above. Also, `Console.Read` won't return what you think it does (see the docs).

Comment: Include code in your post, don't link to an external resource.

Comment: Like user2864740 mentioned, stick with strings.  You can access individual digits by treating the string as an array. For example, if you had 'string phoneNumber = "4441234567"' then you could get the first digit by using "phoneNumber[0]", the second with "phoneNumber[1]", etc

Comment: Sorry for the link -- it's fixed now.  (Only just found this site tonight.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are some constructs you can use to accomplish your goal. I don't want to rewrite your program but I am going to use a `string` instead seven `char`'s. This isn't supposed to be a good to go solution, instead it should demonstrate basic control flow with conditionals and some basic techniques for validating strings.

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (input.Length == 7)
{
    if (!input.StartsWith("555"))
    {
        if (input[0] != '0')
        {
            int temp;
            if (!int.TryParse(input[0].ToString(), out temp)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                // first char is not an int
            }
        }
        else
        {
           // first char is 0 error
        }
    }
    else
    {
         /// 555 error
    }
}
else
{
         // wrong amount of digits

}
```

To print your string you can use a combination of `String.Format` and `String.SubString`

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}-{1}", input.SubString(0,2), input.SubString(3,6)));
```

Comment: @Zain I could have not nested the `if`'s to make it less complete but I thought it might be more helpful to show sequential checking.

Comment: Female here, actually, and this definitely doesn't count as an entire homework solution in my opinion.  :)

Comment: @Willk24 I was aware. I'll give you one other tip to print you string in the correct format :p

Comment: @evanmcdonnal sorry, my previous comment was to Zain.  Still figuring out how this site works.

Comment: @Willk24 If this IS homework, please tag it as such. Also, if evan's answer was helpful, accept it as the answer. Welcome!